# Modify bluetooth low energy scan parameters

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I would like to scan for a beacon which sends advertising packets every 330ms. The payload changes at every advertising interval so that I have to receive as many packets as possible.
I use a Raspberry Pi 3 B and bluez 5.43 (hcitool –i hci0 lescan --passive --whitelist --duplicates). But it seems I only get one advertising package every 1.28 seconds. I have not found a way to set scan window and interval. I have already researched extensively on the Internet, but could not find a solution.
I am very grateful for any help!